# How to allow all the HTTPS URLs to sync in CouchbaseLite Android

Tags: android, https, replication, couchbase-lite

I have an Application which using Couchbase Lite. Till now i was using http and now we need to make little secure. So how to allow all the HTTPS URLs to sync with CouchbaseLite Android?

Comment: What do you mean by "allow it"?  Did you set up an HTTPS Sync Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Configuring SSL](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-ssl/index.html) section of the Sync Gateway documentation it states:

> Sync Gateway supports serving SSL. To enable SSL, you need to add two
>   properties to the config file:
>
> - "`SSLCert`": A path to a PEM-format file containing an X.509 certificate
>     or a certificate chain.
> - "`SSLKey`": A path to a PEM-format file
>     containing the certificate's matching private key.
>
> If both properties are present, the server will respond to SSL (and only SSL) over both the public and admin ports.

To enable the Sync Gateway to use https configure the `SSLCert` and `SSLKey` by following the [Configuring SSL](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-ssl/index.html) documention. Once you have your certificates configured, the Couchbase Sync Gateway will use https.

In fact if you continue to use http URLs, the client won't be able to connect. The Sync Gateway doesn't support simultaneous http and https, it does one or the other. And enables https doesn't change the port that the Sync Gateway uses.